# testing GPRS data reception in server

Tags: gprs

I have server running on winserver2008, I want to test GPRS connection, so I send some data to this server (using its IP), now how can I test data reception in my server? where does this data go? how can I receive it in my server? I'm running up an ASP.NET web app on server
thanks

Comment: You might want to accept some answers to your previous questions.

Comment: hi, I've not got any answer to my last question regarding GPRS, last time I asked a very general question which was banned but now I have a smaller question, just about reading information sent through GPRS in my server, how can I do so?